# Prototype Chain - Is the prototype chain used in this case?

Tags: javascript

I am following along Kyle Simpson's YouDontKnowJS on [frontendmasters.com](http://frontendmasters.com) and am confused by one of his examples.

Here is the example code:

```
function Foo(who){
    this.me = who;
}

Foo.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I am " + this.me;
};

function Bar(who) {
    Foo.call(this, who);
}


Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);

Bar.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert("Hello, " + this.identify() + ".");
}

var b1 = new Bar("b1");
var b2 = new Bar("b2");

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

When calling `new Bar("b1")`; he walks you through what is happening with the prototype chain when b1.speak() is called

- On the `Bar.prototype` the alert function is called, this.identify() is also called.
- When this.identify() is called it is not found on the `this` object (b1) so it looks up to it's prototype.
- Looking at `Bar.prototype` it does not find the identify method, so it looks up it's prototype chain again.
- It now finds the identify method on `Foo.prototype`

Here is what I am unclear of.  When we call `Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype)`, shouldn't `Bar.prototype` now reference a new object which is a copy of `Foo.prototype`, which would have the `identify()` method on it? Why does it have to go up one more step in the prototype chain to `Foo.prototype` to find the `identify()` method?

The official definition of `Object.create()` from the docs:

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When we call `Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype)`, shouldn't `Bar.prototype` now reference a new object which is a copy of `Foo.prototype`...

`Object.create` doesn't *copy* objects. It creates a new object whose underyling prototype is what we pass in. So starting with this:

```
+---------------+
| Foo.prototype |
+---------------+     +----------------------+
| [[Prototype]] |---->|   Object.prototype   |
+---------------+     +----------------------+
| identify: ... |     | [[Prototype]]: null  |
+---------------+     +----------------------+
                      | ...                  |
                      +----------------------+
```

*(I've left out the function object for `identify` for simplicity.)*

...when we do `Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype)`, it creates this:

```
+---------------+
| Bar.prototype |
+---------------+     +---------------+
| [[Prototype]] |---->| Foo.prototype |
+---------------+     +---------------+     +----------------------+
                      | [[Prototype]] |---->|   Object.prototype   |
                      +---------------+     +----------------------+
                      | identify: ... |     | [[Prototype]]: null  |
                      +---------------+     +----------------------+
                                            | ...                  |
                                            +----------------------+
```

Later, after the `Bar.prototype.speak = function...` line is executed, `Bar.prototype` also has the `speak` property.

```
+---------------+
| Bar.prototype |
+---------------+     +---------------+
| [[Prototype]] |---->| Foo.prototype |
+---------------+     +---------------+     +----------------------+
| speak: ...    |     | [[Prototype]] |---->|   Object.prototype   |
+---------------+     +---------------+     +----------------------+
                      | identify: ... |     | [[Prototype]]: null  |
                      +---------------+     +----------------------+
                                            | ...                  |
                                            +----------------------+
```

After `var b1 = new Bar("b1");`, we have:

```
+---------------+
|      b1       |
+---------------+     +---------------+                                                   
| [[Prototype]] |---->| Bar.prototype |                                                   
+---------------+     +---------------+     +---------------+                             
| me: "b1"      |     | [[Prototype]] |---->| Foo.prototype |                             
+---------------+     +---------------+     +---------------+     +----------------------+
                      | speak: ...    |     | [[Prototype]] |---->|   Object.prototype   |
                      +---------------+     +---------------+     +----------------------+
                                            | identify: ... |     | [[Prototype]]: null  |
                                            +---------------+     +----------------------+
                                                                  | ...                  |
                                                                  +----------------------+
```

---

*[In the above, `[[Prototype]]` refers to the object's built-in link to its prototype; there isn't really a property on the object with the name `[[Prototype]]`.
In fact, in ES5 there's no way to directly access the link to the prototype from the object itself, although ES5 added `Object.getPrototypeOf` which lets you retrieve it by passing in the object reference, e.g. `var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject)`. ES6 will add more ways to interact with an object's prototype, including the `__proto__` property that Mozilla's JavaScript has had for years.]*

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! Just to clarify one of my last questions here. On that Bar.prototype, it has the __proto__ which is the public version of the Prototype linkage, then it would also have the speak method as well?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Yes, later, when we add it. Not immediately after the `Object.create`. I should show that.

Comment: +1 for the ASCII art :-) Did you use a tool for drawing these?

Comment: @Bergi: `vim` ;-) I really should have used http://yuml.me or something, though, love their "scruffy" diagrams.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I didn't want to overcomplicate things, but [[Prototype]] probably would be better. I've updated to use that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"When we call Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype), shouldn't Bar.prototype now reference a new object which is a copy of Foo.prototype."

Object.create doesn't create a copy of an object, but it creates a delegation to that object. So you have to go up one more level to `Foo.prototype`because that's what `Bar.prototype` is delegating to.

Comment: Hmmm. I am a little confused by this.  If it creates a delegation to that object, and I add the `speak` property that I have in the code above.  Why isn't Foo.prototype also containing the speak property? Why do the docs say it creates a new object? I'm not questioning, I am just not seeing how this is actually working?